# htaccess: rewrite поддомена в папку со строкой запроса

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Задача: преобразовать строку запрос из `http://anything.example.com/querystring` в `http://example.com/anything/querystring`

Причем еще мне надо некоторые `querystring` преобразовать примерно следующим образом: `nikon/123/something` => `?section=nikon&id=123`, а остальные строки оставить без изменений.

Частично у меня все работает с таким вот htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ %1/index.php?section=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Но это работает **только** для запросов подпадающих под шаблон в третей строке. Т.е. если я размещаю, например, `sitemap.xml` в папке `www/anything/sitemap.xml`, то я его не могу запросить по URLу `anything.example.com/sitemap.xml` - отображается Not found

У меня шаблонов больше, я специально их тут не привожу что бы не загромождать вопрос лишним.

Еще добавлю, что у меня так и не получилось сделать отдельный шаблон под сайтмапы. Не заработало...

Answer (score 0):

Заработало. Вот что у меня в итоге получилось:

Корневой .htacces (/homewww/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Этот рерайт превращает URLы вида `http://anysubdomain.example.com/anystring` в `http://example.com/anysubdomain/anystring`

Далее в каждую папку кладется свой .htaccess (/homewww/anysubdomain/.htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Таким образом, этот рерайт преобразует URLы в зависимости от количества параметров в один из трех запросов. При этом запросы не попадающие под шаблон тоже проходят и, например, файл `/homewww/anysubdomain/sitemaps/sitemap.xml` становится доступным по запросу `http://anysubdomain.example.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml`

Что и требовалось. Всем удачи!